# Input string was not in a correct format. C# error SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a very BIG PROBLEM.
I want to delete a row from my database sql in C#.
here is my code:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Table2 where Name=@N";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", x);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

and finally im get a problem
Input string was not in a correct format.
Help me.
I get the error in first Line.

Comment: what is the value of dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value ?

Comment: In which line are you getting error? most probably, dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0] is empty. So while converting that empty string to Int it may throw error.

Comment: I get Error In The First Line.

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

`dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value` is not a valid integer value, so `Convert.ToInt32` fails.

Did you mean

```
string x = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value;
```

instead?

**Second problem:**

You are comparing the `Name` field to an integer value.  I'm assuming `Name is a _string_ value in the database (otherwise it's poorly named).  When SQL looks for matching values, it will try to convert every value of`Name`in the database to a number.  if ANY value in the`Name` field is not a valid number, the query will fail.

Answer (score -1):

I've read that null or empty string will return 0 (to be confirmed)

Here my guess :

Depending of your country, numbers should be wrote :

1.234

or

1,234

**Solution**

Hugly solution : You can simply do a :

```
Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.Replace(".",","));
```

Good solution : Or use Convert.ToInt32(String, IFormatProvider) :

```
Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

EDIT -1 without comment, i'm please to help.

Comment: I cant put Replace or CultureInfo beacuse when Visual Basic dont give me that and give me another thing Like GetHash , To Strring.

Comment: You titled your question with c#, then complain because my answer is not regarding visual basic??? don't expect any other help

Comment: Wow. I'm making my program in Visual Basic on C# and after I write the Value.    Get me a list of word and in that Replace isn't be right